# Javascript OOP -or- why the heck is this a window

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype

I foolishly thought that a good way to get into javascript and making games would be to make a game in javascript. I used [this](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/) as a tutorial, but I'm an OOP programmer, so I thought I would make it OOP. In brief my new version is this:

```
function Game(){this.whatever = that;...};
Game.prototype.reset = function() {...};
Game.prototype.update = function(dt) {...};
Game.prototype.render = function() {...};
Game.prototype.main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now-this.then;
    this.update(delta/1000);
    this.render();
    this.then = now;

    requestAnimationFrame(this.main);
};

var g = new Game();
g.reset();
g.main();
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, but I get this error:
`TypeError: this.update is not a function`

I added the console.log for this and it shows me that it runs main twice on the correct object, and then suddenly on the third time `this` is the window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(this.main.bind(this));` - read up on [how `this` works in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @nnnnnn That was it. Can you put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I put a quick comment rather than posting an answer because I knew this was a duplicate (of quite a few other questions, but Phil found one before I did).